# Android Dagger 2 and clean architecture implementation, scope errors

Tags: android, dependency-injection, firebase-realtime-database, dagger-2, clean-architecture

I'm trying to figure how to deal with dependency injection with dagger 2 and clean architecture in Android. What i want to achieve is when i click a button, a message will be saved to Firebase Database. And show success message to user. When i build my project i'm getting this error:

> Error:(10, 1) error: com.example.mvpsample.home.HomeComponent
>   (unscoped) may not reference scoped bindings: @Provides @Singleton
>   com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
>   com.example.mvpsample.data.DataModule.provideFirebaseDatabase()

Here my app class:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    private static MyApp app;
    private HomeComponent homeComponent;
    private AuthenticationComponent authenticationComponent;

    @Inject
    Presenter presenter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        app = this;

        homeComponent = DaggerHomeComponent
                .builder()
                .homeModule(new HomeModule(presenter.getView()))
                .build();
    }

    public HomeComponent getHomeComponent() {
        return homeComponent;
    }

    public static MyApp app() {
        return app;
    }
}
```

HomeActivity

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BaseContract.View {

    @Inject
    public Presenter presenter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        MyApp
                .app()
                .getHomeComponent()
                .inject(this);

    }

    @OnClick(R.id.tvHello)
    public void clickTvHello() {
        presenter.writeStringToDatabase("Hi");
    }


    @Override
    public void showSuccessMessage() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

HomeModule

```
@Module
public class HomeModule {

    private final BaseContract.View View;

    @Inject
    public HomeModule(BaseContract.View View) {
        this.View = View;
    }

    @Provides
    public BaseContract.View provideView() {
        return View;
    }
}
```

HomeComponent

```
@Component(modules = {HomeModule.class, DataModule.class})
public interface HomeComponent {
    void inject(HomeActivity homeActivity);
}
```

DataModule

```
@Module
public class DataModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public FirebaseDatabase provideFirebaseDatabase() {
        return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    }
}
```

BaseContract

```
public interface BaseContract {
    interface View {
        void showSuccessMessage();
    }

    interface Presenter {

        View getView();

        void writeStringToDatabase(String string);
    }
}
```

Presenter

```
public class Presenter implements BaseContract.Presenter {

    private final BaseContract.View View;

    @Inject
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;

    @Inject
    public Presenter(BaseContract.View View) {
        this.View = View;
    }


    @Override
    public BaseContract.View getView() {
        return View;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeStringToDatabase(String string) {
        firebaseDatabase.getReference()
                .child("messages")
                .push()
                .child("value")
                .setValue(string).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                getView().showSuccessMessage();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I followed sample projects and tutorials but did not understand what i'm doing wrong here. Not looking for working project but i want to learn what is best practice of this and how to manage and use modules and components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `HomeComponent` is not scoped while your `DataModule` provides a scoped dependency (i.e the `FirebaseDatabase` dependency).

A non-scoped component cannot rely on scoped provider. You either have to remove the `@Singleton` on your `provideFirebaseDatabase()` provider or add `@Singleton` on your `HomeComponent`.

Comment: i'm getting getView() on null reference error in this block:  homeComponent = DaggerHomeComponent
                .builder()
                .homeModule(new HomeModule(presenter.getView()))
                .build();  do you have any idea ?

Comment: try `homeComponent = DaggerHomeComponent.builder().homeModule(new HomeModule(this)).build();`